# css transform flip disabled click event while transition

Tags: html, css, click, transition

The transformation is working by flipping the image when you get hover,
but within the 0.6s of the transformation you can't use the event associated with the click on it, after the image stop rotating you click ant it work.

The click action is just a `<a href>`.

Why this happen?

```
.flip:hover{
    transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Container must have an absolute position!